# Deploy a bot from a specific user so that each user doesn't require configuration

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts

I am trying to create a chat bot that simply sends an email when it is messaged. I'm following the steps outlined by Google on their [Hangouts Chat Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/apps-script-bot).

However, it is asking every user to configure and authorize the scopes. I want the bot to send an email from the owner's email instead of that user.

```
function onMessage(e) {
  var displayName = e.user.displayName;
  var email = e.user.email;
  var msg = e.message.text;
  var dates = msg.match(regex);

  if(msg === 'email me') {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Email Request from ' + displayName, 'Email from chat bot');
  }
}
```

Did I miss one of the steps in the deployment, or is all code run by bots run by the user and not the owner/creator of the bot?

EDIT: Is it even possible? I am getting tons of errors that don't seem to be consistent. For example, sometimes when I try to change the version in a deployment, it fails. And other times, it doesn't. I can't find the consistency.

Comment: Well, who does the script execute as? You specifically chose an option when you published your script.

Comment: When you deploy from the manifest it didn't give me an option. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: True, because Google assumes you configured your manifest file as you desire before deploying. `webapp: { executeAs: "USER_DEPLOYING"}` https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests

Comment: I get the error `Unspecified value of access.` when I try to add that line. Also, when I am reading the docs it says that the webapp key is only recognized when you deploy as a webapp. I am deploying this as a hangouts chat bot as described in this doc: https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/quickstart/apps-script-bot

Comment: Did you also include the relevant value of `webapp.access`? If not, that's why you get that error message. You should probably include more details in your question about how you are deploying, the steps that need to occur in order to reproduce your issue, and anything you've tried already based on information you found when researching the Hangouts Chat API on their documentation site.

Comment: Got it, I figured all of that out, but I am getting strange errors. Changing the manifest may have worked, but I can't figure out how to test it. When I try to change from the HEAD deployment to a deployment for testing with other users I get the error `Failed to edit deployment, please try again later.`